# Redirect from main page

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a conditions:
a) Redirect from help.example.com to example.com/support
b) Redirect from other page, like help.example.com/catalog to example.com/catalog

This all I do in .htaccess file.
My code redirect me only on example.com/support

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}${REQUEST_URI} ^help\.example\.com/(.+)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}${REQUEST_URI} ^help\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ example.com/support/ [R=301,L]
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this rules for yours a - b conditions:

a) Redirect from help.example.com to example.com/support

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^help\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/?)$ https://example.com/support [R=301,L]
```

b) Redirect from other page, like help.example.com/catalog to example.com/catalog

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^help\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: When I input help.example.com it redirect me to example.com

Comment: Yes, I did it! 
This code
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} help.denvic.ru [NC]
  RewriteRule ^$  https://denvic.ru/support [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} help.denvic.ru [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://denvic.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Thaks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples/attempts, please try following htacces rules in your htaccess file. Please place these rules at top of your file, also make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

This will catch `help.example.com` OR `www.help.example.com` both kind of urls.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?help\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://example.com/support [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: I need that help.example.com redirect to example.com/support. But other urls are redirected by mask help.example.com/* -> example.com/*

Comment: @KirillRyzhkov, ok please try my edited rules now, these will redirect from `https://help.example.com` to `https://example.com/support`, let me know how it goes?

Comment: @KirillRyzhkov, please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.